# Javascript drop down menu onchange event only for one fuction

Tags: javascript, html, events, drop-down-menu, onchange

This is what I am trying to achieve: within the function below, when the drop down menu changes, the function will get the value from a textbox and perform look up. I don't wanna add a onchange to the `<select>` tag, as there are other functions linked to the drop down menu. Can I add a on change only to this function below? Many thanks in advance!

```
        <select id="types"> 
            <option value ="food">food</option>
            <option value ="drinks">drinks</option>
        <select>
           function lookup(){
                    var keyword = input.value;//get value from text box
                    var type = document.getElementById("types").value;//get value from drop down menu
                    if (search=="food"){
                    //perform look up
                    //I 'm trying to make it do another search when the type from the drop down menu changes
                }else{

                }       
            }
```

Comment: Not clear what you asking

Comment: Is there a way of adding "onchange" to the dropdown menu, apart from putting it in the dropdown menu <select> tag? I hope it explains the question better.

Comment: Kindly first post your "relevant" HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event handler like this

```js
window.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == "types") {
        lookup(e.target);
    }
});

function lookup(){
  
    alert("here now...");
    return ; // temp exit
  
    
    var keyword = input.value;//get value from text box
    var type = document.getElementById("types").value; //get value from drop down menu
    if (search=="food"){
        //perform look up
        //I 'm trying to make it do another search when 
        //the type from the drop down menu changes
    }else{

    }       
}
```

```html
<select id="types"> 
    <option value ="food">food</option>
    <option value ="drinks">drinks</option>
<select>
```

Comment: Thanks! But where/how shall I add the addEventListener in this case? I assume that if I add it to the drop down menu, function(e) will be triggered each time the menu changes?